# Why Connection timed error in redshift connection?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, http, jdbc, amazon-redshift

I want to connect aws redshift with aws lambda.
But this gives me error that connection timed out

```
            Class.forName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver");
            System.out.println("\n\nconnecting to database...\n\n");

            connStringBuilder = "jdbc:redshift:iam://%s?AccessKeyID=%s&SecretAccessKey=%s&DbUser=%s&SessionToken=%s";
            connString = String.format(connStringBuilder, redshiftClusterURL, accessKeyId, secret, dbUser, token);

            System.out.println("connString is " + connString);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString);
```

Comment: how long did it run before timing out?

Answer (score 1):

Just ensure these steps and let me know if your problem exists:

1. First Ensure that your aws lambda function is running in VPC if its running in VPC you 
   need to configure NAT gateway to connect to the internet and open the outbound port for the database
2. In redshift db open the inbound port for the specified IP ranges of your VPC.

If your aws lambda is not running in VPC.

- Open the all traffic for specified db port in redshift (but it's not recommended and not safe too)

Comment: can redshift and lambda be in the different region ?

Comment: How to do this "Open the all traffic for specified db port in redshift" ?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/gsg/rs-gsg-authorize-cluster-access.html

Comment: use the above link for opening inbound rules and use telnet command (if your are linux user) to check there is no issues in connection